# Error while getting HttpResponse in httpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I am getting error while getting HttpResponse.. From server side is am writing response like this

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");

PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

writer.write("login Successfull");
```

Here is my httpClient code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
PostMethod httpost = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/Test/newServlet");
httpost.addParameter("Email" , "my@emial");
httpost.addParameter("name" , "haseeb");
//Getting Error on this line...Saying "Cannot Find Symbol"
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpost);
```

Comment: did you mean, `writer.write("login Successfull");`? You have to close your String.

Comment: symbol: method.execute(org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod           it is showing red line under the line i mentioned. and i got this example from apache website

Comment: @RussellGutierrez i did this mistake here... not in my code sorry for that.